# Need to resize Partition using Gparted in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning

Screen Capture of my partitions:

[image: Screenshot of partitions]

It does not allow me to resize towards left:

[image: Screenshot of resize window]

I want to resize the sda3 partition so it takes over all unallocated space.

Comment: sda3 is locked because it is in use. You need to boot into a live environment and use GParted from there.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to unmount the partition first!

(make an other temporarily /home dir... remount home to that (or just make a "home" dir on your / partition and unmount /home for a moment.)
Then resize your home partition... and remount your home dir to your new sda3 partition.)

If all fails... boot from a Live-USB... and resize the partition that way. (this is actually easier :-))

Good luck

Comment: It should be done from a live session, period. -1 for the ludicrous suggestion of creating a "temporary home".

Comment: @ChanganAuto What's wrong/ludicrous about my suggestion? It is one of many ways to solve Sumaiya's problem. At least with my option one doesn't need to "reboot". If I wanted to reboot every time I changed/upgraded something... I would have stayed with MS Windows.

Comment: Anyone asking questions such as this one doesn't know yet the bare minimum required to do it safely. It's like asking someone who doesn't know what a scalpel is to perform a surgery. And for absolutely NO GOOD REASON.